# how to perform search on a txt file directly?

Tags: android, algorithm, search, text

I would like to perform a search on a text file directly without storing it into an arraylist or any arrays and the text file will consist of about 100,000 words. I would like to perform the search using binary search to look for a particular word and display its meaning. Is it possible to do so? Are there any samples that I can refer to , to do this? The text file will act as a database.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use a database? It will be faster and convenient.

Comment: sad to say my task do not allow me to store it into the database but i will have to use txt files instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hope this helps... :

```
File file = new File(your file);

try {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                int len = 0;
                byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];
        while ( -1 != (len = in.read(data1)) ){
             if(new String(data1, 0, len).contains(Your String))
                 //Jim, we got him...
        }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```